# DataSet usage when data source is very large?

Tags: c#, database, winforms, sqlite, dataset

I have read several MS articles about when to use DataSets in conjuration with a database from within a WinForms application.  I certainly like the ease of use DataSets offer, but have a few concerns when using them with a large data source.  I want to use a SQLite database to locally store processed web log information.  Potentially this could result in  tens of thousands of rows of data.

When a DataSet is filled via a database table, does it end up containing ALL the data from the database, or does it contain only a portion of data from the database?

Could I use a DataSet to add rows to the database, perform an Update for example, somehow 'clear' what the DataSet is holding in memory, then perform additional row adding?

So is it possible to essentially manage what a DataSet is currently holding in memory?  If a DataSet represents a table that contains 100,000 rows, does that mean all 100,000 rows need to be loaded from the database into memory before it is even usable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have very important points here. These points were raised at the beginning of .Net, when we suddenly moved to disconnected state introduced in .NET.

The answer to your problem is paging. You need to manually code your grid or other displaying device (control) so it queries database in chunks. For example, you have a control (but not grid) that has fields and a scroll. You give your scroll 201 clicks. On 200 clicks, it scrolling through 200 records, on click # 201, it queries database for 200 more. May be, add some logic to remove 200 records, when number of them in the dataset reaches 1000. This is just an example.

To save data you can add it to this same `DataSet/DataTable`. There are few ways of doing it. `DataSet/DataTable` have capabilities to identify new or edited rows, relationships, etc. On a serious systems, Entity Lists encapsulate `Datatables` and provide customizations.

May be you want to look into `Entity Framework` capability. I am not sure if this functionality was included there.

Basically, for some simple application with small data it is Ok to use out of box ADO.net. But in a serious system, normally, there is a lot of ground work with ADO.NET to provide solid Data Access Layer and more additional work to create favorable user experience. In this case, it would be loading data in chunks because if you load 100K records, user will have to wait to load first, then it will be hard to scroll through all of them.

In the end, you need to look at what your application is, and what it is for, and what will be satisfactory or not satisfactory for the user.